# Is the product of two factorial always smaller than the factorial of the sum?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, factorial, products

Let's imagine that we have two positive integers $k_1$ and $k_2$ so that $k = k_1 + k_2$.
Can we assume that for any pair of $k_1$, $k_2$:
$$ k_1! k_2! \leq k! \quad \text{?} $$
Intuitively, I would say yes, but I'm looking for a proof.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the factors on each side of the inequality for a few small values of $k_1,k_2$ (without multiplying them out)? What do you observe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $a_1!\cdots a_k! < n!$ whenever $a_1+\cdots+a_k < n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651431/prove-that-a-1-cdots-a-k-n-whenever-a-1-cdotsa-k-n)

Comment: Hi! I think your intuition is correct: Write both sides more explicitly and you will see that you can cancel some factors and which side is greater.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Martin is right, this is a duplicate with the older post.

Comment: In fact,
$ \frac{(k_1+k_2)!}{k_1!\cdot k_2!}
$
will _always be an integer_ (which I thought was really cool the first time I came across it, and not at all easy to show with pure algebra and arithmetic).

Comment: In the spirit of @Arthur's comment, imagine rearranging $k_1+k_2$ distinguishable balls, $k_1$ of them red, $k_2$ of them blue. Then $(k_1+k_2)!$ counts all possible permutations, $k_1!k_2!$ counts only those permutations where all red balls come first, followed by all blue balls, hence $k_1!k_2!< (k_1+k_2)!$. Finally, $\tfrac{(k_1+k_2)!}{k_1!k_2!}$ counts the permutations still distinguishable when all red and all blue balls look the same, respectively, hence the quotient is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

$$k! = (k_1 + k_2)! = k_1! (k_1+1) \dots (k_1 + k_2) > k_1! \cdot 1 \dots k_2$$

Because $k_1 + i > i$ for natural $i$ and positive $k_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $k' := k!/k_1!$. Then $k'$ is a product of $k_2$ integers (from $k_1 + 1$ to $k$), all larger than $k_1 \geq 0$. In particular, $k'$ is larger than $k_2!$, and so $k! = k_1 ! k' \geq k_1 ! k_2 !$.